# Backup/export custom view automatically from Event Viewer

Tags: windows-server-2008, eventviewer

How can I simply export or back-up a custom view from the event viewer? I do **not** want to export the regular Event logs, such as: System, Application, Security etc. But I want to export automatically my own whole custom view log with event id's.

Comment: You want to export the *events* that you see in your custom view, or you want to export the Custom View itself?

Comment: I want to export the whole Custom View itself.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Custom View properties, select Edit Filter and then switch to the XML tab and copy the filter.

[image]

You can now use the filter with PowerShell, like this:

```
[xml]$CustomView = @"
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[(Level=2 or Level=3) and ( (EventID &gt;= 1000 and EventID &lt;= 2000) )]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
"@

Get-WinEvent -FilterXML $CustomView | Export-CSV "C:\LogFiles\CustomView_$(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-DD").log"
```

Set up a scheduled task to run a script like the above every week

Comment: And how can I put this in a scheduled task in the Task Scheduler? I want this custom view every week on friday in a *.evtx file if possible. Should I run a script or something with the Task Scheduler?

Comment: I've put this in a .ps1 file and ran it with PowerShell but nothing happens. The PowerShell appears, but disappears within 1 second and nothing happens after that. No folder is create on C:\ or such. How to fix it?

Comment: If you used my exact query you probably won't get any results. Run the script from within an existing powershell session to see any errors it might produce

Comment: I still get errors but it's dissappearing so quickly, I can't even read it. Within 1 second it's gone. Can you test your script for errors perhaps?

Comment: I've managed to get it working but now it's saving as a .log file. Isn't there a way to save it as a .xml or csv to open in an Excel sheet? How to make it human readable?? Can I save it as .evtx to open in the Event Viewer?